# form does not work when built with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, events

When I create a form it does not run "$('form').submit(function()..."
I know not work very well with jQuery and do not understand this problem.
Follows a real example.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit( function()
    {
        alert( 123 );
    });


    $('#btn').click( function()
    {
        $('#result').html('<form action="#" method="post"><button>send</button></form>');
    });
});
</script>

<div id="btn">btn</div>

// alert no work
<div id="result"></div>

// alert work
<form action="#" method="post" name="checker"><button>send</button></form>
```

Thank you

Comment: seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/X2UPy/  the "ready" should handle setting the event in time, if not, just move the "ready" at bottom of your page.

Comment: @jamesemanon I'm assuming that the form tag sin't there when the document loads, just the div that get's replaced when clicked. The "works" case isn't when it SHOULD work, but when it does - and thew "no work" case is the one that should work but doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is added after you assigned the event handler, how is it supposed to work?

Assigning the event handler AFTER the form has been created:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click( function()
    {
        $('#result').html('<form action="#" method="post"><button>send</button></form>');

        $('form').submit( function()
        {
            alert( 123 );
        });
    });
});
```

shoudl work, but it's not pretty. Better re-write the whole thing, doing lecture on how to modify the DOM tree nicely (either using jQuery or without it)

Comment: but whenever I want to submit an event must be within the action block?

Comment: I wanted to submit an event to be triggered independently of other elements created. eg "$ ('form'). submit (function () ..." to issue a warning whenever I create and submit a form even through other events. forgive my English

Comment: My code should just do what you thought your original code would. The problem with your code is, that the form doesn'T exist when you assign the event handler, so no element get'S it. After the div is clicked, the form is created - but get'S no event handler attached. So it does just nopthing when submited (well, except the normal submit).

Comment: I did, and yes your code worked. I think I understand what you said ... I then study another way to do :) thanks